# Short 2 wires when a third is powered

Tags: arduino, short-circuit, component-selection

I'm using an Arduino for a home project.

Say I have 2 wires, connected to a breadboard in different columns (not shorted).

When one of my digital outputs on the Arduino is HIGH, I'd like to short these 2 wires.

I can't seem to think of a component or function that would let me do this, but it seems super simple so I'm probably missing something -_-

Help would be awesome, thanks!

Comment: Would a transistor (or enhancement-mode MOSFET) do the job? This would have more limitations than a relay, but is a lot easier (and cheaper)

Comment: @felixphew how exactly would a transistor help me short the 2 wires? I'm still a novice in electronics so perhaps I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there should be no electrical connection between the Arduino and the wires you want to connect, the best device is likely to be a relay. You can get electronic circuits using optocouplers instead of mechanics for isolation that simulate a relay called "solid state relay". In certain circumstances, a single optocoupler (with a series resistor on the LED side) might alread do the job you need.